# How can a shell script perform actions if the file creation time has passed 5 minutes?

Tags: shell-script, files, monitoring

I want to write a script which could be scheduled to run after fixed intervals in such a way that every time when this script runs, it checks the creation timestamp of another file called `HOSTNAME_FA.lck`. If the `(creation timestamp - current timestamp) > 5 Minutes`. It runs another ping test.

Ex: Script Name: `checkFailedNodes.sh`
File which needs to be checked whether its has passed 5 minutes post its creation timestamp: `Hostname_FA.lck`

If the `checkFailedNodes.sh` runs and identifies that the file creation has passed 5 minutes, `checkFailedNodes.sh` script will re-test the Node (HOSTNAME) with an ICMP ping.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What resolution? If resolution of a minute is OK, I would schedule the check via `cron`. If you are doing host monitoring, I might suggest looking at a different solution that can not only execute the check, but also record success/failure and perhaps provide some graphing. For example, we use munin (which is every 5 minutes) to track not just pass/fail but also some averages of the timing, and it sends an alert on a failure.

Comment: I agree this is not the best approach. Our customer had a licensed tool for this but since the license has expired, they don't want to spend their funds in renewing the same. Actually the apart from monitoring, there is a customized solution to feed the network faults to another system hence using the custom scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Several questions here, so let's break them apart.

You want a script that will be scheduled to run in fixed intervals.  This is what `cron` is for.  For example, if you want `/path/to/script.sh` to run every five minutes, add this `cron` table entry:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.sh >> /var/log/myscript.log 2>&1
```

To find files which were last modified more an *n* minutes ago, use `-mmin`.  Do demonstrate with *n* = 5:

```
find /path/to/lockfiles/ -maxdepth 1 -name \*.lck -mmin +5
```

To execute a script for each found file:

```
find /path/to/lockfiles/ -maxdepth 1 -name \*.lck -mmin +5 -exec /path/to/otherscript.sh {} \;
```

The magic token `{}` filename will be replaced with the filename, so the script can be designed to look at the contents of or name of the file and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @DopeGhoti. I understand about using the cronjob however, i want to make sure that the script is scheduled in such a way that it could check the timestamp of the created file and could run exactly after 5 minutes of creation timestamp. Ex: script runs at 10:11:00 and file creation timestamp is 10:08:00, the script could run again on 10:13:00. Not sure if i can do this in cron.

Comment: You could have the cron job run every minute, and use `find [...] -mtime 5` (modified exactly five minutes ago)  rather than `[...] -mtime +5` (modified _at least_ five minutes ago).

Comment: This sounds good. I will try this and get back. One more question, will this work if i have multiple .lck files? If so, will the script to be used in `-exec` command consume the .lck files as inputs one by one?

Comment: Yes, it will work for multiple lock files as you describe.